# Lost connection to MySQL server during query on remote host

Tags: mysql, cppcms

I'm working with cppcms framework with cppdb and mysql and got "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" error when trying to make a query on a remote database.

I also have the same database locally, and the app works ok with that one.

Remote mysql version:
mysqld  Ver 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 for debian-linux-gnu on i686 ((Ubuntu))

Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens if you don't use your framework but just connect to the remote machine and issue the same query using the `mysql` command line utility?

Answer (score 0):

Two questions:

- Do you use connection pooling?
- Do you destroy `cppdb::session` object when you done using it or you are keeping it active all the time?

If you keep `cppdb::session` all the time you probably not need to do it because MySQL closes idle connections after certain time period. It is better to use connection pooling provided by CppDB.

If you are already using connection pooling try to change the `@pool_max_idle` parameter to smaller value.

See: http://cppcms.com/sql/cppdb/connstr.html#speckeys for more details

Comment: I was not using connection pooling, now I am, but still not working (I read connection pooling is activated with @pool_size=sth, is that enough?)