# Connection Pooling: How to deal with prepared statements?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, cppcms

I am developing a website with CppCMS and got some MySQL error. I suspected that this would be the idling problem (as described here: [Lost connection to MySQL server during query on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15102878/7917910)) or something about concurrent connections.

So I thought of trying connection-pooling. **But** I have a list of >50 `cppdb::statement` objects which (I think) hold prepared statements. These need a `cppdb::session` object to be created and up until now I create them once in the beginning of my program and use them over the whole lifetime of the program.

How do I properly implement this with connection-pooling?

Answer (score 0):

I treat prepared statements as having a similar lifespan as a transaction. I know this is not strictly true; a prepared statement can be used over multiple transactions. But it's how I use them.

If you follow this practice, or something pretty close to it, then you won't lose your prepared statements that are associated with one cppdb session.

In other words, create new prepared statement(s) after you acquire a cppdb session. Do one unit of work, then free the prepared statement(s) before you release that cppdb session.

Creating a new prepared statement is a pretty low-overhead thing to do. Many apps create and free statements thousands of times per second. Do you really need to hold those prepared statements for the lifetime of your app?

Keep in mind that a prepared statement allocates a little bit of memory and locks on the server-side as well. It's a pretty small overhead, but it's not free to allocate prepared statements. You shouldn't do it for statements you don't need. And you should free statements when you're done with them, so the server can clean up its memory. Memory leaks in the RDBMS server due to excessive statement allocation is a risk.

Answer (score 0):

cppdb manages connection pooling for you.

See: http://cppcms.com/sql/cppdb/pool.html

FYI: prepared statements are cached withing session. In general it is all done transparently for you. After you prepare the statement it is cached by default.

See: http://cppcms.com/sql/cppdb/stat.html